# ConTeXt: Limit number of words

Tags: context, strings, tokenization, context-lmtx

## Background

Every chapter title contains multiple words, but only the first two words are to be used elsewhere (e.g., page header).

## Problem

I'm looking for a general word splitting solution that can separate words into tokens then select a continuous subset of those tokens. For example:

```tex
\define\ChapterQuote{Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.}

\starttext
  % Output: one percent inspiration
  \splittext[3,5]{\ChapterQuote}

  % Output: Genius is
  \splittext[2]{\ChapterQuote}

  % Output: Genius is one percent 
  \splittext[n-5]{\ChapterQuote}
\stoptext
```

Or possibly along the lines of:

```tex
% 2 is number of words to keep (n-1 keeps all but last)
% boundary means to use the language's natural word break
% strip trims punctuation characters from each word
% striplast trims punctuation from only the last word
\splittext[2][
  boundary=en,
  strip={,},
  striplast=\punctuation,
]{\namedstructurevariable{chapter}{title}}
```

## Code

The following code provides a working example of what works to keep the first two words of a phrase, but isn't robust:

```tex
% Counts the number of words processed.
\definenumber[TextWordCount][]
\setnumber[TextWordCount][0]

% Process only the first two words within some text.
%
% #1 - A word in the text being processed.
\def\processword#1{%
  % Output only two words.
  \ifnum\rawcountervalue[TextWordCount]<3#1\fi%
  \incrementnumber[TextWordCount]%
  \nospace
}

% Resets the word count when processing some text.
%
% #1 - Text to process.
\define[1]\TextProcessWords{%
  \setnumber[TextWordCount][0]%
  {\bf\processwords{#1}}%
}

\starttext
  \chapter{Mr. Hyde (before the transformation)}
  \input knuth
  \section{section a}
  \input knuth
  \subsection{subsection a}
  \input knuth

  \TextProcessWords{\namedstructurevariable{chapter}{title}}

  \chapter{Dr. Jekyll (after the transformation)}
  \input knuth
  \section{section b}
  \input knuth
  \subsection{subsection b}

  \TextProcessWords{\namedstructurevariable{chapter}{title}}
\stoptext
```

The example output document shows that the chapter title has been truncated successfully:

[image: Example output]

## Question

What would be a more concise way to extract the first N words from text? (Note that [\limitatetext](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Cropping_text) and similar work on text width, not word tokens.)

Comment: When reading your first paragraph, I get the impression that what you want is this `\chapter[title={Dr. Jekyll (before the transformation)},marking={Dr. Jekyll}]`. But when I read a long, I do no longer understand if that is what you look for.

Comment: In your example, "Dr. Jekyll" is repeated. If you change the `title`, you have to change the `marking` as well. In my example, changing the chapter title automatically changes every other reference throughout the entire text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in Lua. Splitting a string into words is relatively easy:

```
\startluacode
  local split_word = lpeg.tsplitat(lpeg.patterns.space)
  local str = "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration."
  local words = lpeg.match(split_word, str)
  table.print(words)
\stopluacode
```

which prints

```lua
t={
 "Genius",
 "is",
 "one",
 "percent",
 "inspiration",
 "and",
 "ninety-nine",
 "percent",
 "perspiration.",
}
```

Rest is a matter of creating an interface. I find the interface that you are proposing to be too confusing, so I'll simplify it. You must pass two arguments, which specify the first and last words. If last is is negative, the words are counted from the end:

```
\startluacode
  local split_word = lpeg.tsplitat(lpeg.patterns.space)
  local lpegmatch  = lpeg.match

  local splittext = function(first, last, str)
      local words = lpeg.match(split_word, str)
      local length = #words
      if first < 1 then first = 1 end
      if last < 0  then last = length + last end
      local t = { }
      for i = first, last do
          t[i - first + 1] = words[i] 
      end
      return t
  end

  local str = "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration."
  table.print(splittext(3,5, str))
  table.print(splittext(1,3, str))
  table.print(splittext(1,-5, str))
\stopluacode
```

which gives

```lua
t={
 "one",
 "percent",
 "inspiration",
}
t={
 "Genius",
 "is",
 "one",
}
t={
 "Genius",
 "is",
 "one",
 "percent",
}
```

Now we add an interface to TeX:

```
\startluacode
  local split_word = lpeg.tsplitat(lpeg.patterns.space)
  local lpegmatch  = lpeg.match

  local splittext = function(first, last, str)
      local words = lpeg.match(split_word, str)
      local length = #words
      if first < 1 then first = 1 end
      if last < 0  then last = length + last end
      local t = { }
      for i = first, last do
          t[i - first + 1] = words[i] 
      end
      return table.concat(t, " ")
  end

  interfaces.implement {
     name    = "splittext",
     actions = { splittext, context }, 
     arguments = { "integer", "integer", "argument" },

  }
\stopluacode

\unprotect
\permanent\tolerant\protected\def\splittext[#1,#2]#3%
   {\clf_splittext #1 #2 {#3}\relax}
\protect

\starttext
\defineexpandable\ChapterQuote{Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.}
\splittext[3,5]{\ChapterQuote}

\splittext[1,3]{\ChapterQuote}

\splittext[1,-5]{\ChapterQuote}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]